# How to set default value to select list in MVC during run time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I have view in which it loop through the model and display the details in editable mode. One of the model value is from a select list like below

```
@if (Model != null)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.provider_service_dtls.Count; i++)
     {
    <tr>
    <td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].activity_code_type,
 (SelectList)@ViewBag.activity_code_type, "--- Select Activity Code Type ---", new { @class = "m-wrap" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].activity_name)</td>    
    </tr>

    }
    }
```

Here the `ViewBag.activity_code_type` contain the values `Internal & Standard` when submitting if user selected `Internal` its value `1` will pass to controller and if `Standard` it will be `2` and here the default value will be `"--- Select Activity Code Type ---"`

[image]

Now when i open the same request in edit mode if the model value for `provider_service_dtls[i].activity_code_type` is `1` the select list should be default select as `Internal` and `Standard` if it is `2`.

I coded like this

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].activity_code_type,
 (SelectList)@ViewBag.activity_code_type, Model.provider_service_dtls[i].activity_code_type)
```

But it is not working as expected it is giving the result as below picture

[image]

Here it should default selected `Internal`. What is the change to do achieve the same?

**Edited**

**Model**

```
public partial class provider_service_dtls
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long service_id { get; set; }

        public long preapproval_id { get; set; }

        public string activity_code_type { get; set; }
        public string activity_type { get; set; }

        public string activity_type_name { get; set; }


        public string activity_code { get; set; }
        public string activity_name { get; set; }
        public string internal_activity_code { get; set; }
        public string internal_activity_name { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("preapproval_id"), InverseProperty("provider_service_dtls")]
        public virtual provider_preapproval preapproval { get; set; }


    }
```

**Editor template**

```
@model Provider.Models.provider_preapproval
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.activity_code_type, (SelectList)ViewData["options"])
```

**View**

Inside the for loop i coded like this

```
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls,
new { options = (SelectList)@ViewBag.activity_code_type })
```

I am getting an error

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does
>   not contain a definition for 'EditorFor' and the best extension method
>   overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   string, object)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `@Html.DropDownListFor()` behaves a little differently than other helpers when rendering controls in a loop. This has been previously reported as an issue on CodePlex (not sure if its a bug or just a limitation)

Create a custom `EditorTemplate` for the type in the collection.

In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/provider_service_dtls.cshtml` (note the name must match the name of the type)

```
@model yourAssembly.provider_service_dtls

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.service_id)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.activity_code_type, (SelectList)ViewData["options"], "--- Select Activity Code Type ---")
.... // html helpers for other properties of provider_service_dtls
```

and then in the main view, pass the SelectList to the EditorTemplate as additionalViewData

```
@model yourAssembly.provider_preapproval 

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  .... // html helpers for other properties of provider_preapproval

  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls, new { options = (SelectList)@ViewBag.activity_code_type })
  ...
```

The `EditorFor()` methods accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and will generate the controls for each item in the collection

**Edit**

An alternative is to create a new `SelectList` in each iteration of the `for` loop, where you need to set the `Selected` property of `SelectList`. This means that your `ViewBag` property must be `IEnumerable<T>`, not a `SelectList`, for example in the controller

```
ViewBag.ActivityCodeTypeList = new[]
{
  new { ID = 1, Name = "Internal" },
  new { ID = 2, Name = "Standard" }
}
```

and in the view

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.provider_service_dtls.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].activity_code_type,
    new SelectList(ViewBag.ActivityCodeTypeList, "ID", "Name", Model.provider_service_dtls[i].activity_code_type),
    "--- Select Activity Code Type ---")
}
```

Comment: so i cannot use this inside forloop?

Comment: Well there is another option, but it means that you need to construct a new `SelectList` in each iteration (not very efficient). Its also the only way it will work if you were to use `ListBoxFor()` so I suggest you use an `EditorTemplate` which is a far better approach. Not to mention you now have a reusable control so anywhere else in you app that you need to generate controls for the type, you can just use `@Html.EditorFor()`

Comment: Also your use of `@Html.DropDownListFor()` in the last code snippet is wrong. The 3rd parameter is for generating an `optionLabel` (i.e. the `"--- Select Activity Code Type ---"` you used previously) which is why your second image shows `"1"` as the first option

Comment: I'm confused. Does typeof `provider_preapproval` contain a property named `activity_code_type`? - because the parent `provider_service_dtls` also has a property named `activity_code_type`? My best guess is that the template should be `provider_service_dtls.cshtml` and in the main view assuming its `@model IEnumerable<provider_service_dtls>` then its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m, new { options = (SelectList)@ViewBag.activity_code_type })`

Comment: And please, you really need to start using normal conventions for naming your classes and property names :)

Comment: @stepehmuecke `provider_preapproval` doesn't have property names `activity_code_type` it is only in `provider_service_dtls` but a `provider_preapproval` can contain multiple `provider_service_dtls` and my main view is `@model Provider.Models.provider_preapproval`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82147/discussion-between-sachu-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can try this by using IEnumerable Model type list like

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ReceiverID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)(m => m.activity_code_type), "--- Select ---", new { @class ="form-control" })
```

Hope it will work